# Which is the best approach for a dimension (SCD-2 or a SCD-1 + a whole new dimension)

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, star-schema, scd, scd2

Let´s say I have the following situation:

A dimension Product with some attributes that aren't volatile (Description and Diameter - they can only be changed by a SCD-1 change for correction) and a attribute that can be volatile (Selling Group, it can change over time for the same product).

So, when a change occurs in these volatile attributes of one product, I need to somehow track them.

I have come with these 2 approaches:

**For both:** keep using SCD-1 for non-volatile attributes.

**Approach #1:** Use SCD-2 in product_dim only for volatile attributes.

[image]

**Approach #2:** Make Selling Group a whole new dimension and every sell will track the current value in moment of ETL. No need for SCD-2 here.

[image]

I am new in Data Warehousing and I'm trying to understand which is better and why. One of my aims is to use a OLAP software to read all of this stuff.

Comment: I think the second approach is smart since then you can answer the question "How did the selling group for product X change over time?" more easily.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes to the business needs of your model. I don't know the business enough from your question, but as a rule of thumb if you wanna do analysis by Selling Group (i.e: Total Quantity of all products sold by Selling Group X) then you should create as a separate dimension. So in this case approach#2 is correct.
Considering general concepts and assuming a selling group is some kind of group of products, it doesn't make sense having it as an attribute of a product.

If you want to learn more about Dimensional Modelling I'd suggest looking into [Ralph Kimball's work](http://www.kimballgroup.com) if you haven't done yet. An excellent resource is his book [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/) which covers your question and many more techniques. It's a nice tool to have over your desk when questions like this pop up. Most of the experienced Data Modellers have a copy of it to consult every now and then.